# How to sum elements in pairs in tuple based on a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples (first element, for example string3 may repeat): [('string1',10), ('string2', 200), ('string3', 50), ('string3',45)]. I need to return a list containing 'string' (first elements of tuples) sorted according to the sum of their pairs and I should include them in a list only if the sum is less than a certain threshold.

So, the result if the threshold is 100 should be like ['string3','string1']

Comment: Would you like to show what you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sort_thresh(ls,threshold = 100):
    a = {}
    for key,val in ls:
        a[key] = a.get(key,0) + val
    a = {key:val for key,val in a.items() if val<=threshold}
    return sorted(a,key=a.get,reverse=True)

sort_thresh([('string1',10), ('string2', 200), ('string3', 50), ('string3',45)])
Out[89]: ['string3', 'string1']
```

Comment: Instead of `a.update({key:a.get(key,0)+val})` you could just do `a[key] = a.get(key,0) + val`?

Comment: @RoadRunner, i did not use defaultdict, so I can not do `a[key]` since `a` is an empty dictionary. If you use defaultdict then you will do `a[key]+=val`

Comment: Works for me: [https://ideone.com/Q31eEi](https://ideone.com/Q31eEi)

Comment: @RoadRunner i get your point. The right is evaluated before the assignment happens.  Thanks

Comment: thank you! very elegant solution. why can't we use `key=lambda x: x[1]` in `sorted()` function?

Comment: @Yodo because a is a dictionary and not a list of tuples

Comment: @ Onyambu Why do you write ```key=a.get``` , not ```key=a.get()```?

Comment: @Yodo because key is a function  and not the result of calling a function. `a.get` is a function. of the other hand, `a.get()` is calling the function. try doing `a = {1:2,2:3,3:4}` then do `key1=a.get` and again do `key2=a.get()` you will see that `key1` is a function. but `a.get()` will be an error cause you must have an argument in `a.get` ie `a.get(1)`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
l = [('string1',10), ('string2', 200), ('string3', 50), ('string3',45)]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["String", "Value"])
df = df.groupby(["String"], as_index=False)["Value"].sum()
df=df[df["Value"]<100]
df=df.sort_values("Value", ascending=False)
print(df["String"].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not a concern, you can create a dictionary which will store the sum of second elements for each unique key. Try the following code-

```
lst = [('string1',10), ('string2', 200), ('string3', 50), ('string3',45)]
d= dict()
threshold = 100
for tup in lst:
    if tup[0] not in d:
        d[tup[0]] = tup[1]
    else: d[tup[0]] += tup[1]
item_pairs = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
lst = [tup[0] for tup in item_pairs if tup[1] < threshold]
print lst
```

Comment: What's wrong with this solution? Doesn't it solve the purpose of the OP?

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to sum with a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), then sort in reverse and only keep the keys:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [('string1',10), ('string2', 200), ('string3', 50), ('string3',45)]

counts = Counter()
for string, number in lst:
    counts[string] += number

print(sorted((k for k, v in counts.items() if v < 100), reverse=True))
# ['string3', 'string1']
```